# $routeProvider *still* causing me problems

Tags: angularjs

Help would be very much appreciated.  I have visited probably every single answer regarding $routeProvider on Stack Overflow, reviewed the AngularJS API documentation, consulted with the book I'm reading to learn Angular - and after finding about 5 different ways of doing this (none of which worked), I present to you the following:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" ng-app="ticketRegister">

<head>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>   
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.22/angular-route.min.js"></script>

    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="tickReg.css" />
    <script src="tickReg.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


    <title>EWCC Ticket Register v2.0 by P.A.Pirault</title>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>EWCC</h1>
    <h2>ticket register</h2>
    <h3 class="pull-right">version 2.0</h3>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="well well-lg" ng-view>
<a href="#/Calculator">Calculator</a>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

tickReg.js

```
       var tickReg = angular.module('ticketRegister', ['ngRoute']);

tickReg.config(changeMode);

function changeMode($routeProvider)
{
  $routeProvider.
  when('/Calculator', {
    controller: ticketCalculatorController,
    templateUrl: 'Calculator.html'
  }).
  when('/DB', {
    controller: ticketDBController,
    templateUrl: 'DB.html'
  }).
  otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
}



function ticketCalculatorController($scope)
{
  $scope.price = 
  {
    ppA : 13.95,
    ppC : 6.95,
    ppD : 2.50,
    discountPercent : 0.2,
    gratuityPercent : 0.17,
    taxPercent : 0.06
  };

  $scope.guests = 
  {
    adults : 0,
    children : 0,
    drinks : 0,
    server : undefined
  };

  $scope.bill = 
  {    
    subtotal : 0,
    total : 0,
    discount : "no",
    discountAMT : 0,
    gratuityAMT : 0,
    tax : 0
  };

  $scope.updateTotals = function()
  {
    price = $scope.price;
    guests = $scope.guests;
    bill = $scope.bill;

    bill.subtotal = price.ppA * guests.adults;
    bill.subtotal += price.ppC * guests.children;
    bill.subtotal += price.ppD * guests.drinks;

    if(bill.discount == "yes")
      {
        bill.discountAMT = bill.subtotal * price.discountPercent;
      }

    if(parseInt(guests.adults) + parseInt(guests.children) > 5)
      {     
        bill.gratuityAMT = bill.subtotal * price.gratuityPercent;
      }    

    bill.tax = (bill.subtotal - bill.discountAMT) * price.taxPercent;

    //TOTAL
    bill.total = bill.subtotal - bill.discountAMT - bill.gratuityAMT + bill.tax;
  };
}
```

Comment: Please explain in words (instead of just code) your problem and the solutions that did not work.

Comment: I just figure it out, of course, after hours of turmoil, I post the question, and then 5 minutes afterwards I figure it out....

Comment: Read docs first!. Also note,you don't have **when('/', {})** bit usingotherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });

Comment: Ahh, thank you very much!  I definitely have to do much more reading...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a problem with the ticketDBController not being defined yet.  so I just created an empty function and I at least got some life out of this thing!  Now, to have it keep from going to '/#/' instead of just '/'....